# Oracle reduce result set on field duplication

Tags: oracle, window-functions

I have a result set of a select in Oracle (12c) as the following:

```
GROUP_ID    NAME    ORDERING
       1      AA           0
       1      AA           1
       1      AB           2
       1      AC           3
       2      BA           1
       2      BA           2
       2      BB           3
       2      BC           4
```

I do not know how I could reduce the result set to remove rows based on one column while keeping the other fields. The expected outcome looks like the following:

```
GROUP_ID    NAME    ORDERING
       1      AA           1
       1      AB           2
       1      AC           3
       2      BA           2
       2      BB           3
       2      BC           4
```

I tried to solve it using `group by` but it got rid of the required field ordering. I am not an expert on `window functions` but I think it could be a valid attempt to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your data, it seems that you only need:

```
select group_id, name, max(ordering)
from yourTable
group by group_id, name
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I overcomlicated the issue... I have to wait 8 more minutes before accepting the answer.